# JAXB, XML mashal with @XmlID annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations, marshalling

I have two classes as below, with JAXB annotations. I have looked up about coping with cycles, but I still don't get it. In the example, how do @XmlID and @XmlIDREF work with each other in these two classes? Why are there @XmlDREFs in both classes? Can someone please help to explain how this works? Many thanks in advance.

Class one:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private static int NEXT_ID = 0;
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name="xml-id")
    private String _xmlId;

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String _name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="orders-made")
    @XmlElement(name="orders")
    @XmlIDREF
    private List<Order> _ordersMade;

     protected Customer() { 
        this(null);
     }

   public Customer (String name) {
       _name = name;
       _ordersMade = new ArrayList<Order>();

       NEXT_ID++;
       _xmlId = getClass().getName() + ":" + NEXT_ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return _name;
    }
    public void addOrder(Order order) {
    _ordersMade.add(order);
    order.addCustomer(this);
}
}
```

Class two:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Order {

     private static int NEXT_ID = 0;

     @XmlID
     @XmlAttribute(name="xml-id")
     private String _xmlId; 

     @XmlElement(name="Customer")
     @XmlIDREF
     private List<Customer> _customers;

     @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String _name;

     protected Order() {
        this(null);
     }

    public Order(String name) {
         _name = name;
         _customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

          NEXT_ID++;
        _xmlId = getClass().getName() + ":" + NEXT_ID;
     }

    public String getName() {
       return _name;
    }

   void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
       _customers.add(customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all what is the method public Lecturer(String name) { doing without a return type in the customer class. Did you generated the code ?

Comment: @robin Thanks. I'm so sorry I typed@edited it out according to a slide. That was a typo. I edited it. It should be Customer

Comment: plus there should be an addOrder method in Custmer right ?

Comment: @robin Yes you're right. Thanks and I'm so sorry about this.. I added it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I assume its a many to many relation between Customers and the Orders they made.

@XmlID - You can consider this as the Id for an element(say customer or order its like key in the database).

@XmlIDREF - You can consider this as a reference for some other Object(in case of customer class its order and vice versa, its like a Foreign key in database).

The best way to tell is try the below program

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("Robin");
Order o1 = new Order("Phone");
c1.addOrder(o1);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(c1, System.out);
```

it will give an output like

```
<customer xml-id="Customer:1">
    <name>Robin</name>
    <orders-made>
        <orders>Order:1</orders>
        <orders>Order:2</orders>
    </orders-made>
</customer>
```

The order are shown as order 1 and 2 because the id is the key element in order, now change the @XmlID from id to name in the order class and rerun the program it will give an output like below.

```
<customer xml-id="Customer:1">
    <name>Robin</name>
    <orders-made>
        <orders>Phone</orders>
        <orders>Tab</orders>
    </orders-made>
</customer>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second @XmlID in the answer should be @XmlIDREF? So the field that is annotated with @XmlIDREF wouldn't get included in the XML? For example in Order class `@XmlElement(name="Customer")
     @XmlIDREF
     private List<Customer> _customers;` , so the list of Customer is not printed out in the XML? then what's the use of `@XmlElement(name="Customer")` since we already have the root element as customer?

Comment: Thanks for the correction made the change in the answer. This example I am testing from the Customer perspective, so its like we have a customer with id, name and order(which is another object). Since we have 2 XmlElement both of them will be coming as the child elements. Now the second element is a another Object which have XMLID on the id that's why the ID is getting displayed. the XMLIDREF is like a reference from customer to order.